# How to improve performance of Django ORM already querying with prefetch_related? (many different tables involved)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, query-optimization

I have a Django model which is linked by many other models in a reverse `ForeignKey` relationship, that is many-to-one.

Illustration:

```
class ModelA:
    photo_url = URLField(null=True)


class AbstractModel:
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    modelA_ref = ForeignKey(to=ModelA, on_delete=dj_models.CASCADE)


class ModelB(AbstractModel):
    whatever = TextField(null=True)


class ModelC(AbstractModel):
    whatever = TextField(null=True)


class ModelD(AbstractModel):
    whatever = TextField(null=True)
```

and so on for a dozen more.

I have a serializer for `ModelA`, and a corresponding view for when I call the corresponding endpoint `/api/v1/modela/<uuid:key>/` in Django REST Framework.

Illustration:

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView


class ModelASerializer:
    modelb_field = ListSerializer(source="modelb_set", child=ModelBSerializer())
    modelc_field = ListSerializer(source="modelc_set", child=ModelCSerializer())
    modeld_field = ListSerializer(source="modeld_set", child=ModelDSerializer())


class ModelAView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ModelASerializer
    lookup_field = "id"
    lookup_url_kwarg = "key"

    def get_queryset(self):
        key = self.kwargs["key"]

        return ModelA.objects.filter(id=key).prefetch_related(
            'modelb_set', 'modelc_set', 'modeld_set'
        )
```

Of course, this optimization does not prevent Django from querying all the different tables when the `/api/v1/modela/<uuid:key>/` endpoint is reached, as expected:
[in my situation, the accumulation of queries takes 60% of the 1000ms response time, which is way too long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/592LM.png).

**Hence my question**: is refactoring my database schema to make those models fit into one single table my only option? or is there something more elegant to be done?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: is the value from the screenshot you shared in ms? if so isn't that just around ~120ms in total?

Comment: @BrianDestura This is an excerpt, there are 30 more round-trip requests like this. I'm currently looking into PostgreSQL's materialized views right now, this might be what I need.

Comment: I see. Can you share the whole view and the other serializers? The extra queries might be triggered from there